# If I delete users in parse do I also need to delete the corresponding Installation?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a couple hundred users on parse that I need to delete so that these users can create new accounts using the same username. My concern is the Installations that correspond to these accounts. Do I need to delete these Installations when I delete the accounts? Or will the new accounts create new installations? I wasn't able to find out and if anyone has any insight here that would be awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The installations are representations of the user device, not the user. You may have linked the installation with the user, but that is an explicit addition. When you remove the user it's a good idea to remove the installation, but really it shouldn't matter. If the user keeps your app on their device then they may receive some messages and they would need to create a new account in order to fully interact with the app. If anything in your system requires that a message be associated with a user then you should delete the installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least remove the user object from the installation when a user signs out or the account is deleted.  Someone else mentioned that they had push notifications coming to their test device when a different account was signed in, which leads me to believe that installations are user specific somehow.

You could easily test this, though, by creating a couple different accounts on your app and seeing if it creates new installation objects for each one, or if it just updates the original.